# How can I get the raw query string from Laravel's query builder BEFORE executing the query?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I have a complex query created by a few conditions, and I would like to get the final SQL query from the builder object is about to execute. Can I do that?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can get it doing:

```
$query = DB::table('brands')
                ->join('products','a','=','c')
                ->whereNull('whatever');

echo $query->toSql();
```

But Laravel will not show you parameters in your query, because they are bound after preparation of the query.

So you can also do:

```
print_r( $query->getBindings() );
```

Comment: that returns the query with the placeholders instead of the actual parameters

Comment: to use getBinings() do i need to use any name space or something? @MatteoRiva

Comment: `Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string`  That's what I get when trying to to `toSQL` from a model's query.  It gives me a Builder instance.  How do I get the sql from a builder instance?

Comment: Turns out I had `toSQL` instead of `toSql`, which gave me a completely different result

Answer (score 72):

For debugging this might come quite handy as it returns the SQL with the bindings, so you can instantly put it into the database console.

```
/**
 * Combines SQL and its bindings
 *
 * @param \Eloquent $query
 * @return string
 */
public static function getEloquentSqlWithBindings($query)
{
    return vsprintf(str_replace('?', '%s', $query->toSql()), collect($query->getBindings())->map(function ($binding) {
        return is_numeric($binding) ? $binding : "'{$binding}'";
    })->toArray());
}
```

Comment: This works for me. Much better than the accepted answer above.

Comment: I get a vsprintf too few args

Comment: this is what is was looking for

Comment: Thanks @andi79h! Where would you place it for easy accessibility from any class inheriting Model? since Model itself is in 3rd party library..

Answer (score 7):

Piggy back off andi79h's answer. The function works well, except it's assuming binding would not have any quotes that could break the query.

I added "addslashes" to $bindings to make it a bit safer. Although, ideally, it should be run through mysqli_real_escape_string() if you have an active connection to work with.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

```php
/**
 * Combines SQL and its bindings
 *
 * @param \Eloquent $query
 * @return string
 */
public static function getEloquentSqlWithBindings($query)
{
    return vsprintf(str_replace('?', '%s', $query->toSql()), collect($query->getBindings())->map(function ($binding) {
        $binding = addslashes($binding);
        return is_numeric($binding) ? $binding : "'{$binding}'";
    })->toArray());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Updating @andi79h's answer to handle cases where you have % in the query. (For example, `DATE_FORMAT(report_date, '%c/%e/%Y')` would cause a too few arguments error.

```
/**
 * Combines SQL and its bindings
 *
 * @param \Eloquent $query
 * @return string
 */
public static function getEloquentSqlWithBindings($query)
{
        return vsprintf(str_replace('?', '%s', str_replace('%', '%%', $query->toSql())), collect($query->getBindings())->map(function ($binding) {
            return is_numeric($binding) ? $binding : "'{$binding}'";
        })->toArray());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted line breaks and uppercase mysql keywords in my queries so added to andi79h's answer. Not particuarly elegant and I'm sure there are lots of edge cases it won't work with but I still find it useful...

```
function debug_query($query) {
    $query = vsprintf(str_replace('?', '%s', $query->toSql()), collect($query->getBindings())->map(function ($binding) {
        return is_numeric($binding) ? $binding : "'{$binding}'";
    })->toArray());

    $double_linebreak_words = ['(', ')'];
    $double_linebreak_words_replace = array_map(function($str){ return PHP_EOL . $str . PHP_EOL; }, $double_linebreak_words);
    $query = str_replace($double_linebreak_words, $double_linebreak_words_replace, $query);

    $mysql_keywords = ['ADD', 'ALL', 'ALTER', 'ANALYZE', 'AND', 'AS', 'ASC', 'AUTO_INCREMENT', 'BDB', 'BERKELEYDB', 'BETWEEN', 'BIGINT', 'BINARY', 'BLOB', 'BOTH', 'BTREE', 'BY', 'CASCADE', 'CASE', 'CHANGE', 'CHAR', 'CHARACTER', 'CHECK', 'COLLATE', 'COLUMN', 'COLUMNS', 'CONSTRAINT', 'CREATE', 'CROSS', 'CURRENT_DATE', 'CURRENT_TIME', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', 'DATABASE', 'DATABASES', 'DAY_HOUR', 'DAY_MINUTE', 'DAY_SECOND', 'DEC', 'DECIMAL', 'DEFAULT', 'DELAYED', 'DELETE', 'DESC', 'DESCRIBE', 'DISTINCT', 'DISTINCTROW', 'DIV', 'DOUBLE', 'DROP', 'ELSE', 'ENCLOSED', 'ERRORS', 'ESCAPED', 'EXISTS', 'EXPLAIN', 'FALSE', 'FIELDS', 'FLOAT', 'FOR', 'FORCE', 'FOREIGN', 'FROM', 'FULLTEXT', 'FUNCTION', 'GEOMETRY', 'GRANT', 'GROUP', 'HASH', 'HAVING', 'HELP', 'HIGH_PRIORITY', 'HOUR_MINUTE', 'HOUR_SECOND', 'IF', 'IGNORE', 'INDEX', 'INFILE', 'INNER', 'INNODB', 'INSERT', 'INTEGER', 'INTERVAL', 'INTO', 'JOIN', 'KEY', 'KEYS', 'KILL', 'LEADING', 'LEFT', 'LIKE', 'LIMIT', 'LINES', 'LOAD', 'LOCALTIME', 'LOCALTIMESTAMP', 'LOCK', 'LONG', 'LONGBLOB', 'LONGTEXT', 'LOW_PRIORITY', 'MASTER_SERVER_ID', 'MATCH', 'MEDIUMBLOB', 'MEDIUMINT', 'MEDIUMTEXT', 'MIDDLEINT', 'MINUTE_SECOND', 'MOD', 'MRG_MYISAM', 'NATURAL', 'NOT', 'NULL', 'NUMERIC', 'ON', 'OPTIMIZE', 'OPTION', 'OPTIONALLY', 'ORDER', 'OUTER', 'OUTFILE', 'PRECISION', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIVILEGES', 'PROCEDURE', 'PURGE', 'READ', 'REAL', 'REFERENCES', 'REGEXP', 'RENAME', 'REPLACE', 'REQUIRE', 'RESTRICT', 'RETURNS', 'REVOKE', 'RIGHT', 'RLIKE', 'RTREE', 'SELECT', 'SET', 'SHOW', 'SMALLINT', 'SOME', 'SONAME', 'SPATIAL', 'SQL_BIG_RESULT', 'SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS', 'SQL_SMALL_RESULT', 'SSL', 'STARTING', 'STRAIGHT_JOIN', 'STRIPED', 'TABLE', 'TABLES', 'TERMINATED', 'THEN', 'TINYBLOB', 'TINYINT', 'TINYTEXT', 'TO', 'TRAILING', 'TRUE', 'TYPES', 'UNION', 'UNIQUE', 'UNLOCK', 'UNSIGNED', 'UPDATE', 'USAGE', 'USE', 'USER_RESOURCES', 'USING', 'VALUES', 'VARBINARY', 'VARCHAR', 'VARCHARACTER', 'VARYING', 'WARNINGS', 'WHEN', 'WHERE', 'WITH', 'WRITE', 'XOR', 'YEAR_MONTH', 'ZEROFILL', 'INT', 'OR', 'IS', 'IN'];
    $mysql_keywords = array_map(function($str){ return " $str "; }, $mysql_keywords);
    $mysql_keywords_lc = array_map(function($str){ return strtolower($str); }, $mysql_keywords);
    $query = str_replace($mysql_keywords_lc, $mysql_keywords, $query);

    $linebreak_before_words = ['INNER JOIN', 'LEFT JOIN', 'OUTER JOIN', 'RIGHT JOIN', 'WHERE', 'FROM', 'GROUP BY', 'SELECT'];
    $linebreak_before_words_replace = array_map(function($str){ return PHP_EOL . $str; }, $linebreak_before_words);
    $query = str_replace($linebreak_before_words, $linebreak_before_words_replace, $query);

    $linebreak_after_words = [','];
    $linebreak_after_words_replace = array_map(function($str){ return $str . PHP_EOL; }, $linebreak_after_words);
    $query = str_replace($linebreak_after_words, $linebreak_after_words_replace, $query);

    $query = str_replace('select ', 'SELECT ', $query);

    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a old question, but nowdays, you can get the Sql with all parameters using `->toRawSql()`