# Laravel print last executed SQL query with Query log

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
$mines = Cranks::where([['crank_id', '=', $this->crank_id], ['mine_id', 'like', '%'.$script_value->mine_id.'%'] ])->get();
$querylog =  DB::getQueryLog();
dd($querylog);
exit;
```

This code prints the query log with bind array and all - How can I get the pure SQL, so I can run it in `PhpMyAdmin`

Comment: I would install the [debug bar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar). It lists all queries made by a request.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't. The best I've found is to turn on logging with `SET GLOBAL general_log = 1` in the database, run the query, turn logging back off (set to 0), then check the general log to see the exact query that was run.

Answer (score 1):

using **toSql()** function you can print your query,
like

```
$mines = Cranks::where([['crank_id', '=', $this->crank_id], ['mine_id', 'like', '%'.$script_value->mine_id.'%'] ])->toSql();
echo $mines;
```

Comment: This doesn't show the values is in query - I cannot run in PhpMyAdmin by copy pasting the output of this

Comment: yeah it doesn't show the dynamic values in query but you can separately echo the values and make you query, or you can go through laarvel debugger tool which provide you exact query. anyways sorry.

Comment: Please review this question [how-can-i-get-the-raw-query-string-from-laravels-query-builder-before-executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045732/how-can-i-get-the-raw-query-string-from-laravels-query-builder-before-executing)