# laravel show request value none in query

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I want to filter some data using price but when we echo request value it give correct but when I put this in query it show "?"

**my ajax call**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#price_filter").on("change", function() {
                var price = this .value;
                var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url:"{{ route('indexController.pricefilter') }}",
                    type:"POST",
                    dataType:"json",
                    data:{price,_token},
                    success: function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                        // $("#filterdata").html(response);
                    }
                });
            })
        })  
</script>
```

**my route**

```
Route::post('indexController/pricefilter','indexController@pricefilter')->name('indexController.pricefilter');
```

**my function**

```
public function pricefilter(Request $request){
    echo $price = $request->get('price');

    return $products = DB::table('products')
        ->where('price','=', $price)
        ->tosql();
}
```

**my query result**

```
400
select * from `products` where `price` = ?
```

**it show actually like**

```
select * from `products` where `price` = 400
```

**Here is result**

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "query" => "select * from `products` where `price` <= ?"
    "bindings" => array:1 [
      0 => "1001"
    ]
    "time" => 3.87
  ]
]
```

Comment: Check the output `dd($request->price);`, still null?

Comment: it show the value but query not filter data using price it return all data

Comment: but when we put  this `->where('price','<', $prod_price)` to `->where('price','<', 500)` its work fine

Answer (score 0):

you are seeing the question mark because laravel uses [parameters binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#introduction)

select * from `products` where `price` = ?

when the query excuted on db it will be select * from `products` where `price` = 400

anyway: if you want to your sql query with its parameters you can use this [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51777447/10573560):

```
public function getEloquentSqlWithBindings($query)
{
    return vsprintf(str_replace('?', '%s', $query->toSql()), collect($query->getBindings())->map(function ($binding) {
        return is_numeric($binding) ? $binding : "'{$binding}'";
    })->toArray());
}
```

now:

```
public function pricefilter(Request $request){
    $query= $products = DB::table('products')
            ->where('price','=', $price);
 echo($this->getEloquentSqlWithBindings($query));
return $query;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is normal for Laravel.**

To see the real database query you can use

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
// and then you can get query log
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

So your code would look like this

```
public function pricefilter(Request $request){
    echo $price = $request->get('price');

    DB::enableQueryLog();
    $products = DB::table('products')
        ->where('price','=', $price)
        ->get();
    dd(DB::getQueryLog());

    return $products;
}
```