# Timestamp comparison on where clause randomly working?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have an old database where the column `FastStart_start` and `FastStart_End` are varchars.

Using the Laravel query builder, the following query

```
$referrals = \DB::table('users')->join('order_details', 'order_details.user_id', 'users.id')
            ->join('users as sponsor', 'sponsor.id', '=', 'users.sponsor_id')
            //->where('order_details.created_at', '>=', 'sponsor.FastStart_Start')
            ->where('order_details.created_at', '<=', 'sponsor.FastStart_End')
            ->select('users.username', 'users.email',  'order_details.created_at', 'users.sponsor_id',
                 'sponsor.FastStart_Start', 'sponsor.FastStart_End')
            ->get();
```

gives this outcome:

```
 #items: array:3 [
    0 => {#2792
      +"username": "annalise92"
      +"email": "luisa.grimes@example.net"
      +"created_at": "2020-06-15 21:32:23"
      +"sponsor_id": 2085929
      +"FastStart_Start": "2020-06-01 00:00:00"
      +"FastStart_End": "2020-06-30 00:00:00"
    }
    1 => {#2832
      +"username": "nbarton"
      +"email": "gibson.ibrahim@example.com"
      +"created_at": "2020-06-15 21:32:23"
      +"sponsor_id": 2085929
      +"FastStart_Start": "2020-06-01 00:00:00"
      +"FastStart_End": "2020-06-30 00:00:00"
    }
    2 => {#2836
      +"username": "maxine56"
      +"email": "cwuckert@example.net"
      +"created_at": "2020-06-15 21:32:23"
      +"sponsor_id": 2085929
      +"FastStart_Start": "2020-06-01 00:00:00"
      +"FastStart_End": "2020-06-30 00:00:00"
    }
  ]
```

From the outcome its clear that `FastStart_Start` is less then `order_details.created_at`.

However, if I uncomment the line

```
//->where('order_details.created_at', '>=', 'sponsor.FastStart_Start')
```

from the query builder, the result set will be empty.

How is this possible? Does it have to do with the fact that `FastStart_Start` is a varchar column? If so, why does it not affect the comparison with `FastStart_End`?

Using `toSql` command I see that query builder is creating this query:

```
select users.username
     , users.email
     , order_details.created_at
     , users.sponsor_id
     , sponsor.FastStart_Start
     , sponsor.FastStart_End 
  from users 
  join order_details 
    on order_details.user_id = users.id 
  join users sponsor 
    on sponsor.id = users.sponsor_id 
 where order_details.created_at >= ? 
   and order_details.created_at <= ?
```

Any idea why the resulting set is empty if I uncomment the `where` line?

EDIT: The tosql result for the other query is:

```
select users.username
     , users.email
     , order_details.created_at
     , users.sponsor_id
     , sponsor.FastStart_Start
     , sponsor.FastStart_End 
  from users 
  join order_details 
    on order_details.user_id = users.id 
  join users sponsor 
    on sponsor.id = users.sponsor_id 
 where order_details.created_at <= ?
```

Comment: what about fixing the database?

Comment: @Strawberry its the exact same query, just without `order_details.created_at >= ? and` in the end

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I am considering to fix the database, buts a legacy project and I have no clue where else it is used. However, I am still puzzled why it fails, because comparing strings with timestamps should not fail normally?

Comment: @Strawberry which parameters?

Comment: @Strawberry yes, I don't know what this is, this is just if I call `->toSql()` instead of `->get()` from the Laravel Query Builder. I actually don't use any parameters (see the very first call at the top). I guess the Laravel Query Builder has to compute the table name and will inject in there. I will see if I find a way to also show the parameters

Comment: @Strawberry I just checked using [`getBindings`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20045836/2311074), the first ?  will be replaced with `sponsor.FastStart_Start` and the latter `?` is replaced with `sponsor.FastStart_End`. If I uncomment the problematic line, there is jsut one `?` which is replaced by `sponsor.FastStart_End`.

Comment: For clarity, is it possible to echo those two queries?

Comment: @Strawberry not sure how. I only now that I can print out `toSql()` and `getBindings()`. But if you want, I can replace the above questionmarks from the querys with the associated getBindings

Comment: You can enable the query log via `DB::enableQueryLog()`, then output the query using `DB::getQueryLog()`; it should show the query and the params being used.

Comment: @TimLewis ah, good to know! I just tried and I get an array with 3 values, first is `toSql()` result, 2nd the `getBindings()` and 3rd the `time`.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I actually fixed the database now locally, but the issue remains.

Comment: what version of database it is exactly? also mind posting your table schemas (at least these schema entries related) to all fields in queries? And as for logging the query, the last resort is always to enable query logging on the DB server.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I am using Mysql 5.7 - but I guess no more logs are needed, because the mystical has been solved: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64560558/2311074

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is related to the fact that the final SQL statement is treating `sponsor.FastStart_Start` as a literal string.

The reason for your query working is that from the *string comparison* perspective:

`'2020-06-15 21:32:23' >= 'sponsor.FastStart_Start'` is **FALSE**

as well as

`'2020-06-15 21:32:23' >= 'anystring'` is also **FALSE**

but also

`'2020-06-15 21:32:23' <= 'sponsor.FastStart_Start'` is **TRUE**

as well as

`'2020-06-15 21:32:23' <= 'anystring'` is also **TRUE**

### Solution 1 (Preferred)

Use the `->whereColumn()` method for performing your comparison, so that you tell Laravel that you don't want to treat your *value* as a *string literal*. [This is documented here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses)

```
$referrals = \DB::table('users')->join('order_details', 'order_details.user_id', 'users.id')
            ->join('users as sponsor', 'sponsor.id', '=', 'users.sponsor_id')
            ->whereColumn('order_details.created_at', '>=', 'sponsor.FastStart_Start')
            ->whereColumn('order_details.created_at', '<='. 'sponsor.FastStart_End')
            ->select('users.username', 'users.email',  'order_details.created_at', 'users.sponsor_id',
                 'sponsor.FastStart_Start', 'sponsor.FastStart_End')
            ->get();
```

### Solution 2 (Alternative)

Use a *RAW* clause with the `->whereRaw()` method:

```
$referrals = \DB::table('users')->join('order_details', 'order_details.user_id', 'users.id')
            ->join('users as sponsor', 'sponsor.id', '=', 'users.sponsor_id')
            ->whereRaw('order_details.created_at >= sponsor.FastStart_Start')
            ->whereRaw('order_details.created_at <= sponsor.FastStart_End')
            ->select('users.username', 'users.email',  'order_details.created_at', 'users.sponsor_id',
                 'sponsor.FastStart_Start', 'sponsor.FastStart_End')
            ->get();
```

Both solutions should lead you to the same results, while the treatment at Query building level is slightly different.